# Matching a pair of comments in HTML using regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, unit-testing, mako

I have a mako template that looks something like this:

```
% if staff:
    <!-- begin staff -->
    ...
    <!-- end staff -->
% endif
```

That way if I pass the staff variable as being True, those comments should appear.  I'm trying to test this by using a regular expression that looks like this:

```
re.search('<!-- begin staff -->.*<!-- end staff -->', text)
```

I've verified that the comments appear in the HTML output, but the regular expression doesn't match.  I've even tried putting the comments (`<!-- begin staff -->` and `<!-- end staff -->`) through re.escape, but still no luck.  What am I doing wrong?

Or is there a better way to run this test?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default `.` doesn't match newlines - you need to add the `re.DOTALL` option.

```
re.search('<!-- begin staff -->.*<!-- end staff -->', text, re.DOTALL)
```

If you have more than one staff section, you might also want to make the match ungreedy:

```
re.search('<!-- begin staff -->.*?<!-- end staff -->', text, re.DOTALL)
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  I figured it was something stupid.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

Use an HTML Parser like [HTMLParser](http://docs.python.org/library/htmlparser.html) instead.  See [Can you provide some examples of why it is hard to parse XML and HTML with a regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-rege) for why.

Comment: Excellent point.  For the purposes I'm using this for, a simple regex should suffice.  If I need to do anything more complicated, this is good to keep in mind.

Comment: The point is that a simple regex is never enough even for a simple looking case.